# Android GridView issues

Tags: android, gridview

i have issues while showing some images inside a gridview. The thing is that in some devices with Android 2.3 loads perfect, in others don't. Same happens with Android 4.0+[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code for the layout:

fragment_cameras.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridcams"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="4dp"
   android:columnWidth="150dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

grid_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/snapshotcam"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombrecam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to have 3 images in 1 column and a text below each one? Which one screenshot do you want for result?

Comment: I want the third one that shows the square image and the name below, about columns and other stuff i will fix that but first i need to fix the view of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using hardcoded values for the columnWidth and the Views' layout_width/layout_height attributes.

I don't think your issue has *anything* to do with the device version, but more to do with space-allotment.

If you look at your third image (which has an ImageView width of 100/100dp) and compare that to it's container's width (150dp), you'll notice that it should be physically impossible to fit more than one of those in the same row (else it would extend beyond the screen, and the purpose of the GridView would have been defeated).

You have several solutions to this:

1. *(In my opinion, the best)* Programatically change the dimensions at runtime to be based off percentages of the screen (ie. context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * .25) instead of hard-coded values.
2. Create different layout files for each generalized screen dimension. (sadly, you can still *possibly* run into the same issue with this one).

I personally go with the percentage-based method for all of my apps. It allows me to keep a consistent design across all devices while still using single layout files. I'm sure that people will argue the *proper* approach is #2, even though it is still more susceptible to the issue you're running into (which doesn't make much logical sense, in my opinion).

**Edit** *including DisplayMetrics*:

Using the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) will allow you to easily get the device's Height and Width in pixels, which can then be used to get the appropriate percentage-based values you're looking for.

Width: context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels

Height: context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels

IE. If you want to get 3 rows across, I would recommend setting the columnWidth to:

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * .31f
```

This is just slightly less than 33% (1/3) as using exactly 33% would likely result in the boundaries exceeding what you're looking for, which is why I always recommend going just a tad less than desired (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing is that in the last capture you can see the square image and the name below, but in the other the images are distorted and no name is shown, about the other, yes i'm gonna do that.

Comment: You're very welcome, I hope it helps! And in the second one, like you're saying, it looks like the hardcoded sizes extend beyond the boundaries, except the GridView isn't wrapping them (like in the 3rd) but is instead clipping the children (which is a bit strange). But doing it percentage-based should solve both of those

Comment: Yup, you were right, i've adjusted by hard code the size of the images and now it's being showed as it should. If you please can give me a link or more information about the use of activity.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels i'll really appreciate that

Comment: Updated the post to hopefully explain the DisplayMetrics bit a little better (note: I forgot the getResources() in between 'activity' and 'getDisplayMetrics()' and you should be able to get it even with the default getApplicationContext() call

Comment: Great! Thanks for taking time to help me with this!